# GTranslate for Joomla showing 400 error and stop working

Tags: translation

I am using GTranslate for Joomla in my Joomla websites. It was working fine. Last day I have observed it stop working, and shows 400 errors in the console (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()).

I found in the console,

"https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/l?[object Map Iterator]=[object Map Iterator]"

Joomla version is, 3.10.1, GTranlator version 3.7.6

Answer (score 0):

Download,install,activate,a Mootools disabler.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for joining us.  Your very brief answer has been auto-flagged by the system as being low-quality due to its length/content.  Are you able to [edit] this answer to explain why/how your advice will be helpful for the asked question?  That said it is always great to see unanswered questions receive a response.  Thanks for contributing and please take our [tour] to become more familiar with how JSE works.